# File System Watcher Process called from another class not firing events c#

Tags: c#, events, service, filesystemwatcher

I have a windows service that basically monitors a folder, copies files to a local directory processes the files. The service starts up fine enough calls the Watcher Class and does all of the configuration like it should. So my code works for the setup. However I get 0 events firing. I am wondering if when my `StartFolderWatcher()` method goes out of scope that my object - even though declared at the class level is somehow getting disposed.

So do I need to run the object continuously in a separate thread ? If so can I get an example of how I should do that `Task.Run(()=> myObject)`

Relevant Code is below - if more is needed just ask and I will post it.

```
        static class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                JobProcessor service = new JobProcessor();

                if (Environment.UserInteractive)
                {                 
                    service.RunAsConsole(args);
                }
           }

            private static bool IsDebugMode(string[] args)
            {
                if (args == null) return false;
                if (args[0].ToLower() == "/debug") return true;
                return false;
            }

    }

        public partial class JobProcessor : ServiceBase
        {
            string[] folders = new string[] {"InBoxFolder"};

            HotFolderWatch HFW = new HotFolderWatch();

            public JobProcessor()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

            }

            protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {

                StartFolderWatcher();
            }

            public void StartFolderWatcher()
            {
                FileWatcherInfo[] ServiceWatchers = new FileWatcherInfo[4];

                ServiceConfiguration sc = new ServiceConfiguration();

                for (int i = 0; i < folders.Length; i++)
                {
                    ServiceWatchers[i] = sc.GetWatchFolderSettings(folders[i]);
                }

                HFW = new HotFolderWatch(ServiceWatchers[0]);

                HFW.ReadyToProcess += ReadyToProcess;
                HFW.InBoxFolderDisconnected += OnInBoxFolderDisconnected;
                HFW.LocalFolderDisconnected += OnLocalFolderDisconnected;
                HFW.ProcessFolderDisconnected += OnProcessFolderDisconnected;

            }


            public void RunAsConsole(string[] args)
            {
              OnStart(args);
              Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
              Console.ReadLine();
              OnStop();
            }

         }


            public HotFolderWatch(FileWatcherInfo inbox)
            {


                this.InboxCacheTimeMilliseconds = inbox.CacheTimeMilliseconds;
                this.InBoxFolder = inbox.Folder.Trim();
                this.InboxFileFilter = inbox.Filter.Trim();
            SetInboxWatcher();

           }

            private void SetInboxWatcher()
            {
                InBoxWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(InBoxFolder, InboxFileFilter);
                InBoxWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
                InBoxWatcher.NotifyFilter =
 NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

                InboxCache = MemoryCache.Default;
                InboxCachePolicy = new CacheItemPolicy()
                {
                    RemovedCallback = OnRemovedFromInBoxCache
                };

                InBoxWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnInBoxChanged);
                InBoxWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }

            private void OnInBoxChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
            {
                InboxCachePolicy.AbsoluteExpiration =

 DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMilliseconds(InboxCacheTimeMilliseconds);
                InboxCache.AddOrGetExisting(e.Name, e, InboxCachePolicy);
            }    
    }
```

If in my HotFolderWatch Class I create a FileSystemWatcher in a method as below the code works!

```
private void CreateWatcher()
{

    FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\Tests\JobQueue\InFolder","*.txt");
    fsw.Created += Fsw_Created;
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void Fsw_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    string ex = e.FullPath;
    WatcherChangeTypes ctmp = e.ChangeType;
   // throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the default constructor of FileSystemWatcher uses the filter FileName by default and  I was thinking I would get a last Write or Last Access with out concerning myself with the Name. 
I received good information from here : 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1220094/NotifyFilters-Enumeration-Explained-FileSystemWatc

The article posted in the link is what helped me to solve my issue.

I had to Ste the NotifyFilters.FileName as one of the filters.